# Typescript enforce object value type without lose key type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to enforce the type of an object's value, however ts would lose the key of the object like this:

```
type SomeType = [string, number];

const tmp:Record<string,SomeType> = {
  a: ["string", 0],
};

tmp // as Record<string, SomeType> lose hint of Object keys
```

a way to solve this is:

```
type SomeType = [string, number];

const tmp = {
  a: ["string", 0],
  b: ['']
};

const tmp2 = tmp as {
  [s in keyof typeof tmp]: SomeType;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA2gZ2AJwEsA7AcwBopiBXBAIwnwF0BuAKDYGM5i8pgEYKJgDebKFACGALmwAiPETJzKABiblxUOrKwByPUzYBfdlx58BYAEzD+gqTihiJuKCSgBrCCDgAzfjR-ezAmWXgkVEh2Uw4rawA6IA)

Then, I got right keys and right value type.
But the object `tmp` itself will lose restrict, `tmp.b` is `[string]` but would also treated  So if there is any better way for this situation?

---

Thanks for @jcakz's replay, a way to solve this, using a function with generic inheritance：

```
const satisfiesRecord = <T,>() => <K extends PropertyKey>(rec: { [P in K]: T }) => rec;
```

Comment: Do you just want to restrict the keys of the object?

Comment: No, I just want to restrict values of the Object

Comment: Please see answer to the linked question.  Translating that code here gives [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4V6N).  Also, [please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Thanks for @jcalz 's replay, it's a good method.